# SwiftUI List Row Background not Rendering Off Screen

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm experiencing a weird graphical issue where rows that start off screen do not have the correct background colour when they appear on screen but then forcing a re-render somehow fixes the issue.

Not sure if there is a way to force all elements to render correctly but as far as I can see I am using the modifier correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**LIST VIEW**

```
        List(sessionState.listItems) { groupitem in
            Section {
                ForEach(groupitem.items) { item in
                    ListRow(name: item.name, quantity: item.quantity)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowBackground(ListRowBackground(type: item.type))
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            ListRowButtonView(image: ButtonImage.trash.rawValue) {
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    onDeleteItem(item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            ListRowButtonView(image: ButtonImage.fridge.rawValue, tint: Color.asset.gradientDark) {
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    handleOnMove(item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                            ListRowButtonView(tint: .green, systemImage: ButtonImage.plus.rawValue, label: "Increment") {
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    onUpdateQuantity(item, type: FBKeys.Increment.rawValue)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                            decrementButton(for: item)
                        }
                }
            } header: {
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(groupitem.title))
                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 14, relativeTo: .body))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.asset.gradientPink)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        }
```

**LIST ROW BACKGROUND VIEW**

```
struct ListRowBackground: View {
    let type: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .overlay(
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.asset.bg)
                    .padding([.trailing], 6)
            )
            .foregroundColor(Helpers.shared.getCategoryColor(for: type))
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, when i add another row from the "LIST" tab to the list of the "FRIDGE" tab and **after** when i go to the fridge tab I see the background of the row missing. Once I navigate to any other screen and then return to the "FRIDGE" tab i see the row backgrounds all rendered correctly.

[image]

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: does it also happen if you replace `.foregroundColor(Helpers.shared.getCategoryColor(for: type))`with a static color?

Comment: @ChrisR no it doesn't work either. From the screenshot above looks like only one row is affected but testing it (also with static colours) I can see that the entire list is affected (multiple or all rows lose their background) and when i say background I mean the entire row background not only the colour. I'll try to add a MRE in the next days

Comment: @grenos Did you find solution? I have similar problem.

Comment: @bezoadam i think it's fixed on iOS 16. Not having that problem anymore on Xcode 14 and iOS 16

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me, but it is silly/insane.  I used onAppear for the row view to trigger it to update itself when it becomes visible on screen.  In the onAppear I updated a pointless Bool and made sure the view code was using it, so it would trigger the view reload/updated.

```
struct RowView : View{
    var highlighted : Bool
    @State var pointlessViewUpdatingBool = true 
    
    var body: some View {
        let backColor = (pointlessViewUpdatingBool || !pointlessViewUpdatingBool) && highlighted ? Color.blue : Color( UIColor.systemGroupedBackground )
        
        HStack{
            Text("Cell stuff goes here")
        }
        .onAppear{
            pointlessViewUpdatingBool.toggle()
        }
        .listRowBackground( backColor )
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) //makes whole row tappable
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a valid solution but didn't work for me. No idea why

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by adding the `.drowingGroup()` modifier right after the `.listRowBackground()` modifier. Which makes no sense to me as I'm not using images. But as long as it works ....

**EDIT**

It wasn't working after all. It was only random. :(